# Recuperar valor de Jquery no PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um popup que faz a geolocalização do cliente e gera um cookie, que será usado para fins diversos no site.

Tudo está funcionando, a única coisa que não consegui entender é que, se eu colocar para carregar no site, o script funciona e posteriormente.

No final, eu consigo recuperar os valores em PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.akiachei.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDh8ey5aysev9_03haI8BmrNhHAic9xX80&libraries=places'></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-cookie-master/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function($) {         
            $(".teste").click(function(){
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    if(navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                            var adress = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
                            var urlToGet = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + adress + '&sensor=false';

                            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();                        

                            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                if (ajax.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
                                    if (ajax.status == 200) {
                                        //console.log(ajax.responseText);

                                        var enderecos = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);                      
                                        var cidade = enderecos['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name'];
                                        var estado = enderecos['results'][0]['address_components'][5]['short_name'];
                                        var cidade_estado = cidade + " - " + estado;
                                        $.cookie('cookie_cidade_estado', cidade_estado, { expires: 1 });

                                        alert(cidade_estado);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ajax.open('GET', urlToGet, true);
                            ajax.send();
                        });

                    }  else {
                        //document.getElementById('google_canvas').innerHTML = 'No Geolocation Support.';
                        swal({
                            title: "Oops...",
                            text: "A geolocalização não é suportada pelo seu navegador",
                            type: "error",
                            confirmButtonColor: "#00bae1"
                        });             
                    }

                    var cookie_akiachei = $.cookie('cookie_cidade_estado');

                    if (cookie_akiachei === undefined || cookie_akiachei === null) {
                        var cookie_akiachei_chk = '';
                        var cidade_pre = '';
                        var cidade_pos = '';            
                    }else{
                        var cookie_akiachei_chk = cookie_akiachei;
                        var arr = cookie_akiachei_chk.split(' - ');
                        var cidade_pre = arr[0];
                        var cidade_pos = arr[1];            
                    }
                }); 
            }); 
        });                     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="google_canvas"></div>

    <?php
        echo $cookie_akiachei_php = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >document.write(cidade_pos)</script>"; 
    ?>

    <a href="#" class="teste">teste</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando eu faço isso com o evento click do Jquery, não consigo recuperar os valores em PHP.

Comment: Por quê há `jQuery(document).ready()` dentro do evento `click`, que por sua vez está dentro de um `$().ready()`? Isso não faz sentido, parece que você está escrevendo códigos aleatórios sem nem tentar entender o que ele faz.